# new SimpleDateFormat always returns same reference for a given dateFormat

Tags: java

I was trying to replicate a bug by using the same instance of SimpleDateFormat across multiple threads. However I got stuck with another problem and did not find any answers to it.

This simple code block replicates the issues I am seeing.

```
DateFormat d1 = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy");
DateFormat d2 = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy");
DateFormat d3 = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyy");
System.out.println("d1 = " + d1);
System.out.println("d2 = " + d2);
System.out.println("d3 = " + d3);
```

The results of this operations under java 7 (1.7_0_21) is as follows

```
d1 = java.text.SimpleDateFormat@c5bfbc60
d2 = java.text.SimpleDateFormat@c5bfbc60
d3 = java.text.SimpleDateFormat@b049fd40
```

As you can see that although I am creating new objects for d1 and d2 they end up being the same reference. d3 ends up being a new instance as pattern is different.

Does java compile/runtime do this optimization? Any pointers will be helpful

Comment: Are they actually the same instance (with `==`)?

Comment: And to answer the last question: no, a `new` in Java will **always** result in a new object (unless it results in an exception). The JVM is not allowed to optimize that away.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`SimpleDateFormat` nor `DateFormat` (`SimpleDateFormat` superclass) nor `Format` (`DateFormat` superclass) have a `toString()` implemented, so the `toString()` from the `Object` class is actually executed, whose code is :

```
public String toString() {
    return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}
```

Now, `SimpleDateFormat` hashCode is generated:

```
public int hashCode()
{
    return pattern.hashCode();
    // just enough fields for a reasonable distribution
}
```

Which means that if you create numerous `SimpleDateFormat` instances with the same `pattern`, like in your case, they will have **the same `hashCode`** and hence `toString()` will return the same for these instances.

Moreover, as it has been spotted by rixmath, `SimpleDateFormat` instances with the same `pattern` will also be equal.

Comment: I think you did not get his question. He is asking why are the both references(d1,d2) pointing to the same SimpleDateFormat object. Take a look at its hashcode. It is same.

Comment: Right, but that's not the question. He's puzzled why two variables point to the same object when one would expect differently.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()

Comment: Thanks. I should have digged a bit more before asking this. They indeed are separate references. (Just debugged this code and found it.)

Comment: @assylias Really, I guess I always thought so.

Comment: Two `SimpleDateFormat` with the same pattern will not be equal (`ob1.equals(obj2) == false`) but will have the same `hashCode`.

Comment: Actually. This is not true. Two SimpleDateDormat with same pattern returns true. This is the code in java7<br/>     public boolean equals(Object obj)
    {
        if (!super.equals(obj)) return false; // super does class check
        SimpleDateFormat that = (SimpleDateFormat) obj;
        return (pattern.equals(that.pattern)
                && formatData.equals(that.formatData));
    }

Comment: @rixmath good spot, you are right, my previous comment was incorrect in that case, two `SimpleDateFormat` with the same pattern will be both equal (`ob1.equals(obj2) == true`) and will have the same `hashCode`.

Answer (score 6):

`SimpleDateFormat` actually implements `hashCode` by returning the hashcode of the pattern.

You can verify that there are actually distinct objects by using [`System.identityHashCode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#identityHashCode%28java.lang.Object%29):

```
System.out.println("d1 = " + d1 + " / " + System.identityHashCode(d1));
System.out.println("d2 = " + d2 + " / " + System.identityHashCode(d2));
System.out.println("d3 = " + d3 + " / " + System.identityHashCode(d3));
```

This will print 3 different values.

Comment: The identity hash code of two distinct objects may also be the same. The `==` operator should be used instead to verify that two objects are distinct ones.

Comment: @SpaceTrucker: that's right, it *may* be the same, but it's very unlikely.

Answer (score 5):

They are different instances, try this

```
    DateFormat d1 = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy");
    DateFormat d2 = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy");
    System.out.println(d1 == d2);
```

it prints

```
false
```

as for the same `java.text.SimpleDateFormat@c5bfbc60`, they are based on class name and hashCode. According to Object.hashCode API it does not necessarily return distinct values for distinct objects