# Why do SimpleDateFormat Constructor return the same Object for different Threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, design-patterns

I was fiddling with Threads and was trying out the following code

```
 import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

 public class SimpleDateFormatTest {    

    public static void main(String[] args) {


      Thread A=new Thread(()->{
          SimpleDateFormat a=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
          System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" "+a);
          });
      Thread B=new Thread(()->{
          SimpleDateFormat b=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
          System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" "+b);
          });   


      A.start();
      B.start();

    }

}
```

The output i got was as follows :

- Thread-0 java.text.SimpleDateFormat@f67a0200
- Thread-1 java.text.SimpleDateFormat@f67a0200

Can anyone tell me why same object is passed around for two Threads , when i have assigned individual new object to two Separate Thread local variables (a & b),for sake of thread-safety ?

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: Just because two objects have the same hashCode doesn't mean they are the same object. Print System.identityHashCode(a) (or b), and you'll see different values.

Comment: Ok, Sorry i got my mistake , thanks , they are indeed different , rookie mistake , i got 1570818694 and 65854110 respectively for a and b.

Comment: Look at this answer [new SimpleDateFormat always returns same reference for a given dateFormat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16732233/2078494)

Comment: Yep @pukise , i got it , thanks for lending a hand.